# How to make Apple Mail automatic forward (with rule) keep html format?

Tags: macos, html, mail.app

I use the Mail application (v 5.3) under Mac OSX 10.7

I have created a rule to automate mail forwarding to my team, based on the sender email address.

It works, BUT the forwarded messages are in plain text: Mail seems to lose the html formatting. Images are kept as attachments, and are displayed at the end of the mail.

That looks unprofessional, and it is really annoying when messages contains links, which people now have to copy/paste to open (and I know nobody will).

The recipients all use different mail systems: Mac, Windows or Linux, with a local client or through an webmail such as gmail. The problem really comes from Mail.app, not from the readers' client.

If I forward a mail myself (ie: not using a "rule"), the formatting is preserved, and everybody can read a well formatted mail.

There are very few options in the Mail preferences that seem able to make any change.

In the "composing" tab:

- "message format" is "rich text"
- under "responding" section, I have tried to check "Use the same message format as the original message" (without any effect for my concern)
- in the same section, "when quoting text in forwards:" -> any of the two options has no effect on my problem.

I have, of course, googled the question. If I found some topics (like https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1455763?start=0&tstart=0), I found no solution.

Until recently, I've had a Mac OSX 10.5 system, and I had the same problem. But I thought it was an old and unresolved bug, nobody wanting to work on such a specific and outdated problem. Now my system is almost up to date, I really wonder: is it a bug, or a configuration error?